# Share data between webviews in hybrid App

Tags: cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a React web application running in an hybrid App (wrapped inside a webview) using Cordova.

In the application there are links to a different domain that we open within the same App using `<allow-navigation href="https://*.domain.com/*" />`.

Is there a cross-platform way to share data between webviews opened within the same App without having to go through an external server?

Comment: Are you using the links to navigate the main Cordova app Webview from `www/index.html` to `https://*.domain.com/*`? Or are you using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` to open `https://*.domain.com/*` in a new Webview instance?

Comment: @DaveAlden I haven't looked at `inappbrowser` yet. Which approach would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the inappbrowser approach, because if you navigate the main Cordova webview away from the `index.html` your app has lost its state - it's no longer a Cordova hybrid app, just a wrapped web page.

Bi-directional communication between the main app webview and inappbrowser webview (on Android & iOS) is now possible due to [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/362) being merged.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. We'll give it a try! :)